# Why is this person deserving of death?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, tractate-brachot, capital-punishment, eliyahu-hanavi

> הַהוּא גַבְרָא דְּקָא מְצַלֵּי אֲחוֹרֵי בֵּי כְּנִישְׁתָּא, וְלָא מַהְדַּר אַפֵּיהּ לְבֵי כְּנִישְׁתָּא. חֲלַף אֵלִיָּהוּ. חַזְיֵיהּ, אִידְּמִי לֵיהּ כְּטַיָּיעָא, אֲמַר לֵיהּ: כְּדוּ בָר קָיְימַתְּ קַמֵּי מָרָךְ?! שְׁלַף סַפְסֵרָא וְקַטְלֵיהּ.
>
> To reinforce the gravity of this prohibition, the Gemara relates: A certain individual prayed behind the synagogue and did not turn to face the synagogue. Elijah the Prophet passed by and appeared to him as an Arab [taya’a]. Elijah said: “This is how [kadu bar] you stand before your Master?” Elijah drew a sword and killed him. ([Berakhot 6b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.6b.20))

Rav Huna says that someone who prays behind the shul is wicked and then Abayey clarifies that this is only when a person also faces away from the shul. This is then followed by the story of Eliahu HaNavi brought here. So I understand from the genera that this is a wicked person based on his actions but what makes him deserving of the death penalty?

Comment: See Ezekiel chapter 8. Bowing away from someone is incredibly offensive.

Comment: So is this Gemara why many people leave the shul by stepping backwards out of it as opposed to just walking out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tosfos, Berachos 6b (ד"ה אחורי בית הכנסת) says that

> מיחזי כשתי רשויות

Meaning the guy's making it look like there are two gods of equal power. Avodah Zara is a capital crime, so it seems to fit.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Adam and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: thank you for your answer. How is he doing this exactly?

Comment: @Dude: please see 6b here https://dafyomi.co.il/berachos/tosfos/br-ts-006.htm

Comment: @Dude Jews pray in the same direction (towards the Temple/Jerusalem). If this guy is praying in the opposite direction, it looks like he's praying to another god. Idol worship is a capital crime.

Comment: @Adam yes I see that now. the link with tosfos explains that

Answer (score 5):

The [Maharsha](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Berakhot.6b.12?lang=bi) asks this question, and answers that this is the reason why the Rif changed the girsa from Elyahu to instead refer to a non Jew

> חלף אליהו וחזייה אידמי ליה כטייעא כו'. ברי"ף ל"ג חלף אליהו כו' אלא חלף ההוא טייעא חזייה כו' וכן נראה מפרש"י וכן נראה קצת **דמשום שעשה כך אינו דומה שיהיה חייב מיתה** שיהרגהו אליהו ויש ליישב גירסתנו דאידמי ליה כטייעא לא קאי אאליהו אלא אאותו איש דלא הוה מהדר אפיה כו' קאי דהוה אידמי ליה לאליהו שאינו ישראל אלא ערבי ולכך הרגו אליהו וק"ל

The [Ben Yehoada](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Berakhot.6b.6?lang=bi) explains that it was Eliyahu, and although such an action isn’t punishable on bais din, it is punishable in the heavenly court.

> ועל הקושיא שיש בגרסתינו לומר איך הרגו, יש לומר דאף על גב דאינו חייב מיתה בידי אדם חייב מיתה בידי שמים שעבר על דברי חכמים שאמרו אסור להתפלל אחרי בית הכנסת, והעובר על דברי חכמים חייב מיתה בידי שמים, ולכך אליהו זכור לטוב שהוא מלאך מן השמים הרגו בדיני שמים

Comment: Great answer! I wonder if any early manuscripts support the Rif.

Comment: Just checked and Ms. Paris 671, Ms. Munich 95, and some others indeed have טייעא instead of אליהו.